# Do Heinlein's novels mention a plausible zero-gravity cat litter box?

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, robert-a-heinlein

I have read a lot of science fiction works with cats being the optimal space pet. I know Heinlein was a cat person, and I am thinking he had a solution for cats doing their business in space, but I can't recall what or where it was.

I posted a couple of questions [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12274) and [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10498) about the reality of cats and litter boxes in zero/micro gravity.  The comments on those questions are leaning towards it being impossible, but I feel sure that of all the cat in space stories there must have been practical solutions.  I have searched for Pixel (*[The Cat Who Walks Through Walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_Who_Walks_Through_Walls)*) and litter box without finding anything. I have not read about Pixel for a while so I don't recall how much time he spent in zero G, but I do recall his needs being a priority.

**Did Heinlein ever identify how his cats were able to pee/poop in space, in this or any other of his novels?**

Comment: I'm now imagining a cat with a colostomy bag strapped to its back. Although whether that would work in zero-G or micro gravity is another (off topic) question entirely.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't recall it ever coming up in RAH works; Pixel was usually in Dora or Gay Deceiver.  Gay had gravity in the bathroom annex and Dora had it all over.  There were a number of cats in his stories, but I don't recall any of them spending much time in space, although I suppose the 'Flatcats' might count. I don't recall any discussion of their litter needs, but that doesn't mean much -- it's been years since I read The Rolling Stones.  (The Flatcats were basically the forerunners of Tribbles; lots said about their eating, not so much about excretion.)

Comment: I've edited to make it clearer that you're not after a scientific solution, but rather wanting to know if it's been discussed in a specific universe.

Comment: Might want to clarify that to in Zero G; Pixel could use the bathroom in space with no problem, as several spaceships had artificial gravity :)

Comment: @Richard The OP wasn't specifically looking for an example in RAH's work, merely citing them as an example of a thought out cat-in-space scenario I thought.

Comment: @Xantec - In which case, the question should be closed as "Science, not science-fiction".

Comment: If you are just looking for a thought out scenario, a simple idea (seen in 2001, but for humans, for exercise) would be a centrifuge.  With a little training, it would give the cat a gravity mimicking environment to do his business, and wouldn't have to be terribly large.  RAH's titular character 'Waldo' used something similar for a Cockoo clock, as I recall.

Comment: @Richard - I disagree; he's asking for any well thought out examples in SciFI, and using RAH as a possible example, but there are sure to be other SciFi cats in space.  The cat from Forever War by Halderman leaps to mind, although I don't recall it's bathroom needs ever being addressed.

Comment: @Richard Not necessarily. Regardless, the question may be better worded to ask about zero-G pet facilities in general, rather than for cats specifically. Presumably dogs, targs and other alien animals would have somewhat similar needs. One example may fit the needs of all.

Comment: Thinking on as many Space cats as I can, including Pixel, Skitty, the cat from Forever War and others.. Most authors seem to have dodged the issue courtesy of some from of artificial gravity...

Comment: If it's a general discussion of whether something has been "thought out in fiction" then it's too broad

Comment: Given that nobody's found any examples at all yet, it's hardly "too broad". All I can think of is some kind of mini-carousel, but I don't recall ever seeing the issue addressed in any SFF work.

Comment: @richard - Again, I must respectfully disagree.  A 'practical solution from SciFi' quantifies it nicely.  Given the trouble we are having coming up with even one, that suggests a pretty small population or possible answers.  If need be, it could be quantified to a 'the first' type question to specifically fit the rules, but it's a pretty tight niche with few (well, no) answers forthcoming so far -- I think it's a good question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I give you: [NASA's Animal Enclosure Module (AEM)](http://gravitationalandspacebiology.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/606/628)

Comment: @JoeL. As that is a real world example you might want to post it as an answer on the [Space.SE](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12274) question the OP mentions. A free range cat could be trained to go use a modified box like that (with olfactory queues perhaps) to do its business, with the waste being "swept" up by a continuous air flow.

Comment: @Xantec: Given what I know of cats, I think the larger question would be, "Once you've taught the cat to use the litterbox, how long will it be before it does its business somewhere else to show it's annoyed?"

Comment: My sister the actual scientist (nutrition studies) suggested cat-diapers.

Comment: I checked [the story I thought about when I read this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104757/31936), and the cat on the space station has "a litter box that used magnetic gravel and gentle suction to overcome the problems of a zero-gee environment". It's not Heinlein, but is this what you are looking for (based on the original version of your question)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not aware of an instance in which Heinlein explains how cats would relieve themselves in space. However, [Jack McDevitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_McDevitt) includes a zero-gravity litter box in the short story "The Cat's Pajamas". The litter box

> used magnetic gravel and gentle suction to overcome the problems of a zero-gee environment.

The story is available in the short story collection [Armored](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12377899-armored). A description of the story by the author can be found [here](http://www.johnjosephadams.com/armored/author-interviews/interview-jack-mcdevitt/) (H/T [@Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104758/31936)).

Comment: Would you like to offer this as a suggestion at my [related question on space?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12274/how-would-a-zero-gravity-cat-litter-box-work) I have linked back to this in the comments there.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I don't have an account on that site and don't plan to create one. Feel free to answer your question on that site using this solution.

Comment: I did not realize this was a 2012 work, I half recall a similar story and (possibly unrelated) solution that would have been published in between 1950 and 1980.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question in the title: I have all the novels listed in the [Heinlein bibliography on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein_bibliography), and too many short stories and anthologies for me to want to check them against the bibliography. In none of them have I found anything about dealing with a cat's bowel motions in zero-G.

The only novels of Heinlein's I've found that mention a cat other than in passing are:

- Farnham's Freehold
- For Us The Living
- Friday
- Magic, Inc
- Space Family Stone
- The Cat Who Walks Through Walls
- The Door Into Summer
- The Puppet Masters
- To Sail Beyond The Sunset
- Magic, Inc

and none of these mention the subject (incidentally the cat in *Space Family Stone* is an alien *flat cat*). In fact only *Space Family Stone* and *The Cat Who Walks Through Walls* deal with weightlessness at all.

The only short story I've found is *Ordeal in Space*.

I'm reluctant to claim definitively that Heinlein never mentioned a zero-G cat tray (there may be other stuff of his I'm unaware of) so I'll content myself with saying only that I have been unable to find such a mention. The nearest Heinlein comes is in *Space Family Stone*. The family are loading up the bicycles they're going to recondition and sell on Mars, and there is the following exchange:

> ‘Mind you don’t try to pass them off as new. But it looks to me as if you had taken too big a bite. When we get these inside and clamped down, there won’t be room enough in the hold to swing a cat’ much less do repair work. If you were thinking of monopolising the living space, consider it vetoed.’
>
> ‘Why would anyone want to swing a cat?’ asked Meade. ‘The cat wouldn’t like it. Speaking of that, why don’t we take a cat?’
>
> ‘No cats,’ her father replied. ‘I traveled with a cat once and I was in executive charge of its sand box. No cats.’